# java3d thumbwheel won't zoom my model, right button won't move it either but left is fine

Tags: java-3d

I have a piece of Java3D that display my model perfectly, I've imported it using the STLFileReader class. I can move it with the left mouse button but the right button has no effect. The thumbwheel forces a redraw but is not zooming the image.

I have a similar piece of code that looks at a model of the seabed imported from a point cloud and it works perfectly. I can't see any difference between the two that would cause this.

Can anyone think what I may have done wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should ask your question on the official JogAmp forum in the Java3D subsection. Maybe it has something to do with the size of the bounding volume, you should check that with Blender, MeshLab or any other modeler able to load STL files.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this wasn't an error in my code, but a scaling issue of some sort.

My model was centred on 0,0,0 but had extents going to +/- 10,000 in each direction. When I divided them by 1000 to +/- 10 everything started to work including zoom.

It wasn't a bounding sphere issue (I don't think) as I could previously see the whole structure. So I'm guessing I needed to scale the zoom and translate to the size of my drawing somehow. The effects of zoom and translate were so minor against the size of my model that they no visible effect.

Hope this helps someone else.